# Strongloop - hasOne relation

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, has-one

I am having some trouble with setting up a hasOne relation, which probably comes from me understanding the relation wrongly?

I have 2 Models, one user model, and one location model. What I want to add now is a relation between user and location, meaning a user has a current location. But if I set up a hasOne relation on the user model with the location, I end up with a userId property in the location. But this is completely wrong, since several users can have the same current location, so the user model should store the location id, not the location the user id. So how can I achieve what I want, so that I can afterwards query the user and include the current location?

I can of course add a property to the user and store the id of the location there, but then I can't as easily include the location in a user request. So I would prefer using relations to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is a bit unclear, given the comments of Brian's post, but if you absolutely need Users to share a given set of locations then you would be better off using `User` `belongsTo` `location`.

This will create a `locationId` field in `User`, and you will be able to `GET` `api\Users\{userId}\location`

Eventually, you can set a `location` `hasMany` `User` to retrieve from a given location all the users in there

Comment: This is a much more straightforward answer than mine; I thought I had tried a `belongsTo` relation but must have gotten the models switched or forgot to clear out the old schema.

Answer (score 2):

The relation name is referring to the relational meaning of "has one," which means that for each user, there exists one (and only one) entry in the location table. Each user "has one" entry in the location table, and if your data needs to show that two users have the same location, it just means the location table would store identical location data with different userIds. This is still perfectly fine for relational mapping, and allows you to do User.location calls.

What you are looking for is slightly different, which would be "Location *hasMany* Users," because you will be sharing location entries with multiple users. Read this as "for each location entry, many users could share it." You'll have to query a bit differently and use the `include: ['location']` filter when you want to return the User with location data included (otherwise you'll only get the locationId value).

Relation builder:

```
$ slc loopback:relation
? Select the model to create the relationship from: Location
? Relation type: has many
? Choose a model to create a relationship with: user
? Enter the property name for the relation: users
? Optionally enter a custom foreign key:
? Require a through model? No
```

location.json:

```
{
  "name": "Location",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "lat": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "long": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "users": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "locationId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it does make more sense now. And yes it seems your solution is what I am looking for. But you said I can use an include filter to get the location with the user object with does not seem to work for me. I only get an error `Relation \"location\" is not defined for user model` which kind of makes sense since the relation is now defined on the Location model, not the user model. I can of course use the locationId in a second call to get the location, but if it's possible with one call that would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: To make it simple and be able to use the built in methods that will get attached to the model, just use the User hasOne Location relation and store the same location with a different User ID. Sure this uses more storage, but it's not much in the grand scheme of things (assuming location is just a few columns worth or lat/long). You're trading a tiny bit of extra storage for less code/complexity.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have other models with relations to the location model as well, so I don't want to create new instances of the same location for every user and then have to update all my other relations accordingly as well. But it's ok, I will just use the locationId in a separate call to get the location, or maybe a remote hook to provide it in a single call.